# I want to print age in my bill from dob. dob is stored in $_SESSION but its not printing the age in html page

Tags: php, html, css, session

If anyone help to fixed this code i will be very thankfull.

[image: code]

Comment: <?php 
$dob = $_SESSION['dob'];
echo $dob;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Age:<?php $from = new DateTime('$dob');
      $to = new DateTime('today');
      echo $from->diff($to)->y;
    ?>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags. And also [please don't post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: I dont post that start session code here... I used start session in my page.i have the acces in that page.only the prblm is dob is not printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php session_start();  ?> 
    <?php $dob = $_SESSION['dob'];  ?> 
    <html> 
    <head> </head> 
    <body> Age:<?php $from = new DateTime($dob); $to = new DateTime('today'); echo $from->diff($to)->y; ?> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

You didnt start the session on that page.

And I changed new DateTime('$dob') to new DateTime($dob) because is variable.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `session_start()` , so the first element is not working and your `$dob` is undefined.

With every warning and error module enable, I'm pretty sure your page should display a big error saying you don't have access to your session

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php